# Display a "approx. time to answer" on sites

Tags: feature-request

*Is there a reason why on all the sites there is no approximate time to answer? And can we have one?*

I know for some sites (Stack Exchange) one can get answers in seconds, but for some (won't point the finger :P) it would be nice to know how often one should come back and check? I am not a fan of email notifications.

Not sure if considered before? Does not need to be calculated all the time, but once per day should be fine, I would think. Of course, if it can be calculated more often, why not.

Anyhow, just an idea...

And before someone answers with: be patient...
some people are just not :P

Comment: Patience young grasshopper. Patience. You'll get your answer when you get your answer.

Comment: i knew it :P hahaha

Comment: It doesn't exist because no one implemented it. And what's the benefit of implementing it? Any attempt will be approximate - some questions take seconds, some never get an answer. How would having this feature help?

Comment: @Oded "it would be nice to know how often should one come back and check"

Comment: @b0x0rz *"Dear Meta. The site says I can expect an answer in about 3 hours, but it has been 4 hours already..."* ... let's not do this.

Comment: It's not been done because there is no possible way to know how long any question will take before anyone answers it.

Comment: @Bart hahaha of course :P i could see that happening

Comment: @JonW therfore the word "approximate" ;)

Comment: "You *might* receive an answer within approximately 1 minute - 24 months"

Comment: @JonW - "5 seconds to never", more likely ;)

Comment: @Oded surely you can hack in a 6-8 weeks timer :)

Comment: @Bart - it will be ready in [6-8 weeks](http://cznp.com/6to8weeks/index.php).

Comment: no matter what i do with the sliders, it is ALWAYS 6-8 weeks :p

Comment: It would be like the Microsoft Copy File dialogue. "10 minutes remaining...two days remaining...30 seconds remaining...5 seconds remaining...-20 seconds..."

Comment: "It would be like the Microsoft Copy File dialogue. "10 minutes remaining...two days remaining...30 seconds remaining...5 seconds remaining...-20 seconds..."" -- @tombull89 which kind of shows that it has benefits even wildly accurate as that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good answers take time, so ... slowly ... step ... away from the monitor and make yourself a coffee or something. Isn't it much nicer to have answers waiting for you when you get back instead of staring the answers into existence?

But unless your questions are so well written that an answer can be formulated unambiguously and without having to ask clarifications, I would suggest to not stay away for more than a few minutes; it's likely that **potential answer candidates may not have much patience either** ;-) in fact, a likely better statistic would be the **waiting time for either a comment or answer**.

If you feel strongly about this, I would suggest you go to [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/) and write a time-to-respond approximator query, based on:

- The tag; for simplicity you should probably identify the primary tag.
- The time, relative to the timezones of the top 10% users on above tag.
- Public holidays for kicks.

Assuming the quality and complexity of the question is average, calculate the following statistics:

- Waiting time where first response is a comment
- Waiting time where first response is an answer

If you think it's good enough, you can write another post here, demonstrating how it will be a boon to the site :)

Comment: hey, that is not a bad suggestion. if nothing i can make it only for myself ;) that would teach you all ;)

Comment: @b0x0rz I would be interested too, and I'm not just saying that :)

Answer (score 3):

The time-to-answer depends not only on which site you're on, but also on many other factors such as topic, time of day, quality/difficulty/clarity of the question, etc.  Trying to estimate a site-wide approximate value may not be very viable.

That aside, I worried that such a feature might encouraging users to "go away and come back again in X minutes". Especially in the early stages where the question is still prominent on the front page, the OP should really be on hand to answer queries and update the question when required.

Comment: +1. One of the most frustrating aspects of answering questions is having somebody post a question, then disappearing without answering follow up questions. I'd rather not have anything potentially encouraging that, or giving even the implication that they *will* get an answer in that time period.

Comment: yeah and i, on the other hand, refresh like a lunatic, trying to answer those questions that may come but don't :P at least not as fast as seconds/minutes after posting. "early stages" means different things on different sites.